# how to create stylish mails with html format php

Tags: php, html, email, file-get-contents

I'm sending mails with php but i'd love to send them just as the as the ones i receive from twitter or kinda. So i have followed some tutorials in order to achieve this.. i've used: file_get_contents to send the emails and i created a html page that will be shown in the email's customer. Here is the code of my html page:

1. ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <style type="text/css">
     h2{
        font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
        color: #0088cc;
        text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #aaa;
         }
        h4{
       font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
       text-align: center;
       color: #aaaaaa;
         }
   </style>

       </head>
       <body>

        <center>

    <h2 class="font-effect-shadow-multiple">Bienvenida a </h2>
    <br>
    <!--<img src="cid:image.jpg" alt="lupa" >-->
    <h4>Hola nuevamente queremos darte la BIenvenida a nuestro sitio de 
            <strong><font color="#0088cc">Hoteles. </font>
    </strong>Para comenzar queremos <br> darte algunas sencillas instrucciones
   que te ayudaran a familiarizarte mas con esta util apliocacion</h4>

    </center>

      </body>
     </html>
   ```

And here is my php code that calls the html page above:

```
     <?php 
     require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
     $correo = "alejo.ferguson@yahoo.com";
     $usuario  = "alejandito";
     $direccion = "londrescopacabana";
     correo($correo, $usuario, $direccion);

    function correo($correo, $usuario, $direccion){
       $correo2 = substr($correo, 1,3);
   $usuario2 = substr($usuario, 1,2);
       $direccion2 = substr($direccion, 2,3);

   $mail = new PHPMailer();
   $mail->IsSMTP();
   $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
   $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
   $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
   $mail->Port = 465;
   $mail->Username = "hunternova01@gmail.com";
   $mail->Password = "2203march1988";
   $mail->SetFrom('hunternova01@gmail.com', 'Alejandro Ferguson');
   $mail->AddReplyTo("alejo.ferguson@gmail.com","Alejandro Ferguson");  
   $mail->Subject = "Bienvenida al Sitio HotelFinder";
   $mail->IsHTML(true);
   $mail->AddEmbeddedImage('../img/img_correo.png',
       'Hotel','../../img/img_correo.png', 'base64', 'image/png' );
   $mail->AddEmbeddedImage('../img/lupa.jpg', 'Lupa', '../../img/lupa.jpg', 
      'base64', 'image/jpg');   
   $mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents('../correos/correo_formato.html'));
   $address = $correo;

 $mail->AddAddress($address, "Robertin");
 if(!$mail->Send()) {
 echo "Error al enviar: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
 echo "Mensaje enviado!";
 }
    }
```

Well everything works just fine, but here is my problem check out at the image, (this is what the recepient receives on his/her email account):

[image]

Now comes my questions: 
-HOw can i place the images/icons in the placed desired? i mean f.e: i'd like to place the house icon next to the title mail, how can i do that?

-How can i insert text on the html page i got? f.e: i need to show the user an url which will contain info about how to confirm his/her new account. As you can see on the php code there i have 3 variables: $correo, $usuario, $direccion so i need to form an url like this:
         localhost://android_4/correos/activa_cuenta.php?
          user=$usuario&recor=$correo2&ccionre=$direccion2";

Remember that this can only be done where the mail is formed: the php code page... How can i add this piece of code to be shown at the html page?

I'd be more than thankful with your help!!

Comment: Just use HTML, and since this is going to be read in an email client, obviously you have to use absolute paths of images to your fully qualified domain name. Don't make the images attachments, in other words.

Comment: thank you for replying! that's the problem my friend! 'cause the whole thing of creating a formatted html mail is due to the need of sending the customer an url, and we didn't want just to show up the simple url but to look really nice!! so i we can't avoid doing that...

Comment: To make what I'm saying clearer, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have this line:

```
 $mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents('../correos/correo_formato.html'));
```

Whatever is in that file needs to include the images with fully qualified domain name, rather than you attaching them to the email.  For example:

```
<html><head><title>correo formato title</title></head>
<body>
   <img src='http://whatevermydomainis.com/img/lupa.jpg' />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OK i get it! you're right! there's no need to attach anything there but on the html page right ? But still i don't find the solution to how to add an url and show that url in that mail... thanks for replying!

Comment: I don't get the question about the URL. If you just do `echo ".../activa_cuenta.php?user=$usuario&recor=$correo2&ccionre=$direccion2";` the values of the variables will be printed out into the HTML because PHP does that when you use double quotes.